# understanding "item for item in list_a if ..." PYTHON

Tags: python

I've seen the following code many times, and I know it's the solution to my problems, but I'm really struggling to understand HOW it works. The code in particular is:

```
item for item in list_a if item not in list_b.
```

For example, with `for each in list`, I can understand that it is going through the list, and doing a loop for each item in that list. with `while x < 10` is easy to comprehend, and most other loops and similar commands are pretty straightforward. Even the `for item in list_a if item not in list_b` makes sense to me, though that alone doesn't seem to work without that first `item`...But for some reason, I just don't understand how that first `item` fits into the equation, other than "because" (which just isn't a helpful answer), what it represents.

Would someone be able to help me sort this out, or be able to expand this equation out into several equations that might help me wrap my head around how it's working. it's so much easier for me to use these tools when I understand how they work, and this ones baffled me for a while.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be clearer if you split it into three parts:

1. Take `item`;
2. From `for item in list`;
3. Where `item not in list_b`.

The reason the list comprehension syntax is like this is firstly because that reflects the expanded version:

```
for item in list: # 2.
    if item not in list_b: # 3.
        new_list.append(item) # 1.
```

and also because you don't necessarily want just `item`, for example:

```
new = [x ** 2 for x in old if not x % 2]
```

will create a `new` list with the squares of all even numbers in `old`.

Comment: It is important to note that the returned object will be a `list` not a single `item`. But this is a good explanation of list comprehensions!

Comment: Thank you. Your two breakdowns filled in what I was missing perfectly, and makes it make a fair bit more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are building a list by looping through(and filtering) another list

The first item is the thing you are putting into your result list

You can also do stuff to the element such as

```
[i*2 for i in range(6)]
```

The output will be:

```
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Essentially the first "item" lets you **control** what you put into your result list

Comment: This answer would be better if you used the actual data type names (list), and it doesn't even include conditions in comprehensions.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fixed the data type. The condition is not really what he is asking. His focus is on the FIRST item, and condition doesn't really come into play. Simplification sometimes makes it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension `[item for item in list_a if item not in list_b]` is equivalent to using the `filter` function:

```
filter(list_a, lambda item: item not in list_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the line of code you're referring to is called a list comprehension. Basically, as you know, it is a way to create a list of items "on the go", with the ability for conditionals as well.

When you create a list comprehension, you are building a list, and you need to to tell Python what you are putting into that list. If a list comprehension was simply:

```
new = [for item in list_a if item not in list_b]
```

It would not be a list comprehension at all, because you are simply iterating and not storing any thing in the new list. So, in order to actually save items into the new list, you need:

```
new = [item for item in list_a if item not in list_b]

# for each item in 'list_a', if 'item' is not in 
# 'list_b', add item to 'new'
```

Which is the same as:

```
i = 0
for item in list_a:
    if item not in list_b:
        new[i++] = item
```

Think of "that first `item`" as the value you are putting into the list. Essentially a list comprehension enumerates, keeping track of the *index* and does something like this for each iteration:

```
new[index] = item
```