# Python startswith() not removing all matches

Tags: python

Not sure if I am doing anything silly here but I am trying to remove all items in a list which starts with `00:00:00.` but not all items are matched.

```
tc = ['00:00:00.360', '00:00:00.920', '00:00:00.060', '00:00:02.600', '00:00:05.960', '00:00:01.040', '00:00:01.140', '00:00:01.060', '00:00:01.480', '00:00:00.140', '00:00:00.280', '00:00:01.200', '00:00:00.400', '00:00:01.220', '00:00:00.380']
for item in tc:
    if item.startswith(str('00:00:00.')):
        tc.remove(item)
print (tc)
```

Result:

`['00:00:00.920', '00:00:02.600', '00:00:05.960', '00:00:01.040', '00:00:01.140', '00:00:01.060', '00:00:01.480', '00:00:00.280', '00:00:01.200', '00:00:01.220']`

Expected Result:

`['00:00:02.600', '00:00:05.960', '00:00:01.040', '00:00:01.140', '00:00:01.060', '00:00:01.480', '00:00:01.200', '00:00:01.220']`

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: Do not remove from the list during iterating over it! The iterator position changes, that's why it doesn't remove everything.

Comment: This answers your question: [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping over list and removing entries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558845/looping-over-list-and-removing-entries-in-python)

Comment: @h4z3: mine is a couple of years older. "Baffling crowds since 2011!"

Comment: @usr2564301 I had trouble finding a good question while reporting duplicate, there are so many of them. :D

Answer (score 8):

that is because you change `tc` while iterating through it.
you can achieve your goal with a simple list comprehension:

```py
tc = [item for item in tc if not item.startswith('00:00:00.')]
```

Comment: Or you can create a copy of the list, and delete only in that new list. The solution @Tal gave is better, but maybe 'create a copy' is easier to understand.

Comment: To understand this list enumeration, visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620091/understanding-item-for-item-in-list-a-if-python